# JAX-WS how to write client interface using return types instead of of OUT params

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I want to connect to Webservice using JAX-WS, so I created Interface

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/")  
public interface MessageService {       
    @WebMethod(operationName="AddMessage", action="http://tempuri.org/IAddService/AddMessage")              
    public AddMessageResponse addMessage(
            @WebParam(name="Sender", targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/") String Sender, 
            @WebParam(name="Message", targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/") String Message);       
}
```

AddMessageResponse.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"addMessageResult",
"messageId"
})@XmlRootElement(name = "AddMessageResponse")
public class AddMessageResponse {

@XmlElement(name = "AddMessageResult")
public String addMessageResult;
@XmlElement(name = "MessageId")
public Long messageId;   
}
```

Code to obtain proxy is straightforward:

```
Service service = Service.create(new URL("https://localhost:8080/WS/AddService.wsdl"), new QName("http://tempuri.org/","AddService"));                  
MessageService ws = service.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/","IAddService"), MessageService.class);
System.out.println(ws.addMessage("tim", "hello"));
```

but give me null.
The thing is that when I use tools like wsdl2java, generated client interface have those Holders generic types for return params:

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "AddMessage", action = "http://tempuri.org/IAddService/AddMessage")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "AddMessage", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "test.addMessage")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "AddMessageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "test.AddMessageResponse")
public void getMessage(
@WebParam(name="Sender", targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/") String Sender, 
@WebParam(name="Message", targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/") String Message
    @WebParam(name = "AddMessageResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<String> addMessageResult,
    @WebParam(name = "MessageId", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<Integer> messageId);
```

But I really dont want to use them, so how can I make my code to work with return types instead of OUT parameters?

Comment: Please post your web service implementation for `MessageService` interface. Perhaps you did not modify the generated implementation, if any, that it usually returns `null` as default for `addMessage` method.

Comment: Hello @OwenBringino this is not a deal for sure.

Comment: @Krzysztof Szewczyk Exactly the same thing happens to us, did you find any solution to this?